# Accessible in-line modal?

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility, wai-aria

When it comes to accessibility, what is the proper design pattern or technique for appending an inline panel that would have a header, body text, and optional close button?

For context, I've been tasked with creating an accessible multi-select quiz question that appends a correct or incorrect feedback panel under the question after the user presses submit. I think normally this sort of feedback would appear in a modal popup that covers the other content and traps focus, but this particular design needs the feedback panel to appear in the page directly under the submit button, and still allow the user the tab back through the answer options (even though they would be aria-disabled after submitting).

The feedback panel would have a title header, body text, and an optional close button. There would be no close button if the user got it all correct or they ran out of attempts.

Is there a suitable aria-role or known design pattern for this sort of appended panel? And what should I send focus to once the feedback panel appears, the header? The close button?

In case its relevant, for the multiselect answer options I am using native checkboxes with `<label>`s

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Option 1

The first would be to add `role="alert"` to the appended box (assuming you will only add it once per page as otherwise we would use `aria-live`).

This would then be announced to screen reader users.

### Option 2

Option 2 is that you can just append the box to the page and use focus management. So the box appears and you would move focus to the heading of the box via JavaScript (with `tabindex="-1"` on the heading for example). This needs to happen from an expected action (so "submit answer" button that you said you have).

I would probably go with option 2 as it is the easiest way to not introduce more accessibility issues by mistake.

There are other ways you can achieve this with `aria-live`, `aria-labelledby` etc. etc. but the above two options are the most straight forward.

Comment: One caveat with **Option 1**. If you dynamically add a container with `role="alert"`, the text within that container will **not** be announced automatically to the screen reader user. Alert roles are live regions and live regions must exist on the page **before** you add content to them. But you *could* have an empty alert container on the page and when the user submits their answer, add content to that container.  Then it **would** be announced. I prefer using `aria-live` in this situation but @graham is correct that you could manage the focus (option 2) and get the same affect.

Comment: Thank you both for the insightful info, I really appreciate it. I'll attempt option 2. It's a Single Page Application, so I believe the overall page holder is going to have aria-live="polite" on it; Hopefully this doesn't cause issues.

Comment: @slugolicious are you sure on that one? Multiple aria-live regions are well known as problematic but `role="alert"` works well when dynamically added (as long as there is only one) - See this fiddle: https://codepen.io/vloux/pen/JOwxmO. If it is a problem then can you let me know in which SR / browser combos as I use this technique in production and will need to update it if it is an issue! Thanks in advance!

Comment: @GrahamRitchie, you could be right. I've been doing this too long and dynamic live regions were not supported for a very long time.  Perhaps browsers have gotten better since then.

Comment: @slugolicious oh I can relate to the doing this too long bit, the amount of times I say something, then someone points out it was an IE6 issue makes me realise I am older than I act! 